# I really want to know where am I doing wrong in this program. Everything is working up to readAll function, where I get Access violation executing

Tags: c++

In this program i want to create a pointer to struct student, that has the members(numarMatricol, nume, gen, nota, a pointer to function void readData(student*st) and a pointer to function void writeData(student*st)).

I tried different ways of getting this done, but I can't understand what is not working. By the way, I did not deallocate the memory, I just wanted to see if it works up to this point

this is the function file

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
#include "Student.h"

using namespace std;

void readData(student* st) 
{
    char buff[30];
    int len;
    cout << "Introduceti numarul matricol: ";
    cin >> st->numarMatricol;
    cout << "Introduceti numele studentului: ";
    cin.ignore(30, '\n');
    cin.getline(buff, 30);
    len = strlen(buff);
    st->nume = new char[len + 1];
    strcpy_s(st->nume,len+1,buff);
    cout << "Introduceti genul (M/F): ";
    cin >> st->gen;
    cout << "Introduceti nota: ";
    cin >> st->nota;
}

void writeData(student* st) 
{
    cout << "Datele studentului cu numarul matricol " << st->numarMatricol << ": " << endl;
    cout << "\tNumele: " << st->nume << endl;
    cout << "\tGen: " << st->gen << endl;
    cout << "\tNota: " << st->nota << endl;
}
//initializing the pointer at function inside of each struct student
void initPointerFunctie(student* st, int n)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        st[i].read = &readData;
        st[i].write = &writeData;
    }
}
//calling the function read
void readAll(student* st, int n) {
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        st[i].read(&st[i]);
}

//calling the function write
void writeAll(student* st, int n) {
    for(int i = 0; i<n;i++)
        st[i].write(&st[i]);
}
```

this is the header

```
#ifndef STUDENT_H_
#define STUDENT_H_

struct student {
    int numarMatricol;
    char* nume;
    char gen;
    float nota;
    void(*read)(student*st);
    void(*write)(student*);
};

void readData(student* st);
void writeData(student* st);
void initPointerFunctie(student* st, int n);
void readAll(student* st, int n);
void writeAll(student* st, int n);


#endif
```

and this is the main

```
#include<iostream>
#include "Student.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    student* v;
    int n;
    cout << "Introduceti numarul de studenti: ";
    cin >> n;

    v = new student[n];
    readAll(v, n);
    writeAll(v, n);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: 1) Did you try stepping through your code with a debugger? 2) `st[i].read(&st[i]);` What does `read` point to, at the point this line is executed? You never set it to anything.

Comment: Ahhh, Thank you so much, I forgot to call the initPointerFunctie function in main :))